# How to include an admin area in a static site blog

Tags: netlify, hugo, static-site, static-site-generation

I had built a simple hugo blog for my mother, and hosted it with a Forestry.io + Github + Netlify combo. Forestry provided a nice wysiwyg editor to write her blogs, and netlify hooks would generate static site and update the site.

Now that forestry is gone, I am looking a way to integrate some way of having a secure page where I can self host a cms like setup. How do I do it, in Static-site? There is no backend server for it.

Comment: you can host it in your subdomain. So, something like ```admin.domain.com```

Comment: main issue us how to enable admin features without actually having backend. I am actually regreting using an SSG for my moms blog.

Comment: does she use ```markdown``` file to write her blog ?

Comment: forestry provided a wysiwyg editor for her. I am trying to teach her basics of markdown. But at present, since forestry is not available anymore, she is sharing google docs to me, which then I am converting to markdown and pushing to my github.

Comment: to be honest, foresty is not gone, they're just focusing on tina CMS now. You can still host your own cms and make the SSG to pull the data when building